# Ionic Capacitor page is flashing on some Android devices

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor, ionic5

I made an application using ionic, first releases were using Cordova, but my last release uses Capacitor, now some customers are no longer able to use the last release on their Android phones(specially Tecno devices running on Android 8.1, Alcatel 1 devices,...), the application keeps blinking or flashing they can't click anywhere, for some it messes up the whole page like on the screen shots

[image: Messed up page]
[image: Messed up page]

[image: Correct Page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was du to Google Chrome latest version (`92.0.4515.115`),  devices with PowerVR GPUs (GE8320 or GE8100) running on Android 8.1 were impacted. The bug has been fixed by Chrome Team.

You can follow the discussion on this link [Issue 1222095: Icons not displaying after latest Chrome update on Android 8.1 devices](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1222095)